# Data structure for permutations in Java

Tags: java, arrays, permutation, sortedset, ordered-set

I need to store a permutation of n integers and be able to compute both the permutation of a value and the inverse operation in efficient time.

I.e, I need to store a reordering of values [0...n-1] in such a way I can ask for position(i) and value(j) (with 0 <= i,j <= n).

With an example—Suppose we have the following permutation of values:

- [7,2,3,6,0,4,8,9,1,5]

I need the following operations:

- position(7) = 9
- value(9) = 7

I know libraries in C++ for that, such as: https://github.com/fclaude/libcds2

Is there any structure or library in Java that allows to do that and is efficient in space and time?

Comment: Are there any guarantees about duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

If there are no duplicates, the `List` interface will suit your needs.

It provides the following methods:

- `List#get(index)` returns the element with index `index`
- `List#indexOf(element)` returns the index of the first encountered `element`